# Are there any good tutorials on performing optical flow transforms for a sequence of still images?

Tags: bluetooth, artificial-intelligence, robotics, opticalflow

I want to experiment with guiding an RC car via my laptop using bluetooth and an X10 camera to snap the pictures.  Basically I want to create the DARPA not so grand challenge of guiding my RC car around the house and avoiding obstacles and teaching it how to navigate.  Not terribly practical but fun to mess with.  Any suggestions on books, tutorials or alternatives to optical flow that accomplish the goal of allowing the RC car to perceive motion relative to its optics.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to go for any vision processing applications is most likely OpenCV.  It is an open-source library with many common vision functions implemented for you.

It is available in C++ and Python.

As far as actually implementing optical flow, there is a pretty decent reference with lots of comments available here: http://robotics.stanford.edu/~dstavens/cs223b/

I think that you will find that the included pdf files provide good context for what the code is actually doing.